# limit values in a combo box based on multiple entries in a field on another form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms

this is not exactly a cascading cmbo box (i don't think).

I have 2 subforms that are linked by a datasheetID to a MainForm
form1A -  I have a unique number for a piece of equipment (TrapID) - with some details 
form1B - I want to choose only the unique pieces of equipment (TrapID) that have been entered into this form (dataSheetID) - and enter some other associated information.

at the moment it's showing all unique ids for equipment across multiple forms

I've tried cascading cmbos but it gives me 1 choice at a time which I don't want - just because that's not the way my data sheets are set up

thank you!

[image]

Comment: You want all TrapID associated with a specific DataSheetID to show on Species Per Trap? So why is it showing only TrapID 2? What is query? What is code? You say something is showing ALL then you say something is showing only 1 and neither satisfy. What multiple forms? You describe only 2. Really not clear what you want.

Comment: you have set `1..5` traps. shows `form1`. And you caught one in `trap 2` shows `form2` what is your problem?